# How to retrieve an object inside an object in EJS

Tags: javascript, json, ejs

I am trying to retrieve the "info" section of the JSON below. As you can see in my code I use the

```
<%= person['person_details']%>
```

to retrieve that section of JSON. This returns [Object Object]. What I want to do is retrieve everything in the info section of JSON a.k.a: "jim" "bob" "true" and "Two guys walk into a bar, one says: ow!". Some of the JSON doesn't have the same fields (I added another example below). I've tried doing...

```
<%= person['person_details'][0][1]%>
```

But this gives back an error. If I remove the [1] it gives back an empty quantity in my drop down menu.

```
<div class="personForm">
    <form>
        Select Parameters
        <select id="personIdList">
            <% data1.forEach(function(person) {%>
            <option><%= person['person_details']%>
            <% }); %></option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>


//JSON THAT IM ATTEMPTING TO EXTRACT
"person_details": {
    "info": {
        "name": "Jim",
        "lastName": "Bob",
        "isMale": true,
        "favJoke": "Two guys walk into a bar, one says: ow!"
    }
},
//EXAMPLE 2
"person_details": {
    "info": {
        "email": "bobsmit@gmail.com",
        "lastName": "tim",
        "isMale": true,
        "momMaidenName": "felicia"
    }
},
//EXAMPLE 3 (info changes to information)
"person_details": {
    "information": {
        "email": "bobsmit@gmail.com",
        "lastName": "tim",
        "isMale": true,
        "momMaidenName": "felicia"
    }
},
```

Comment: `<%= person['person_details']['info']['name']%> // Jim`? And so forth...

Comment: @Marcus  'code <%= person['person_details']['info']%>'  works and returns an [Object Object] but...
'code<%= person['person_details']['info']['name']%>' returns an error

Comment: What *error* does it return?

Comment: @Marcus Ahh the error it is returning is because not everyone has the same order in the JSON. Some people Only have first name, some have email, etc... So it returns an error because it is unable to extract name specifically from all of the objects since I am using a .forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the keys of each person's respective `person_details`. From there you'll use the keys ass accessors to the values.

For example:

```
<% data1.forEach(function(person) {%>
   <option>
     <% Object.keys(person.person_details.info).forEach(function(key) { %>
       <%= person.person_details.info[key] %>
     <% }); %>
  </option>
<% }); %>
```

This is a dynamic approach and will work with any set of key/values you have in your `info` hash.

If your `person_details` information hashes contain different names, you can monkey patch that in the loop (although I would recommend you normalize your data instead and use the first example).

```
<% data1.forEach(function(person) {%>
   <% var infoKey = infoKey = Object.keys(person.person_details)[0]; %>
   <option>
     <% Object.keys(person.person_details[infoKey]).forEach(function(key) { %>
       <%= person.person_details[infoKey][key] %>
     <% }); %>
  </option>
<% }); %>
```

In this example, you dynamically find the name of the info key and set it to an `infoKey` var. From there you use that as the accessor.

Comment: How do I set the key value?

Comment: Care to elaborate, please? Your question is a bit ambiguous. You don't need to set anything in your case since your data is coming from `data1`.

Comment: Ahhh I see, sorry about that, wasn't thinking in the right manner. One more question if you don't mind. Lets say that the "info" part of the JSON changes to "information". Would this still work? I'm going to edit the bottom of my code and add another example for you to look at.

Comment: This would not work... but would easily be tweaked to work. Just change both instances of `info` to your new key. In your case `information`. And sure thing... just let me know when you've updated the post.

Comment: Just updated my code, check out example 3 at the bottom.

Comment: May I ask why your datasets are so inconsistent? Do you have the ability to normalize them? As in, ONLY use `info` or `information`.

Comment: First of all I just want to say thank you, you answered my first question spot on. When I implemented the code, other problems started to pop up, and that is because the dataset is not normalized. At my current knowledge level, I do not know how to normalize them, but I am going to do some experimenting and see what I can do.

Comment: That would definitely the best approach. If you expect all your data to have a specific structure then you're ruling out a lot of bugs. I'll update the answer to accommodate your datasets as-is. If it in fact helps you out, care to mark it as accepted :D?

Comment: If you could update the answer that would be great!I will certainly accept. Thanks again :)

Comment: Although I do reccommend you fix the data, I've added the example which dynamically finds the info key :)